# Testing a cached action

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5

I used to have a simple action;

```
Action.async {
    logger.trace("Retrieve and fill gaps peril ->" + peril + " :: region -> " + region)
    val events: Future[Seq[SingleEventYear]] = annualAtomFillInternal(peril, region)
    events.map(s => s.mkString("\n")).map(res => Ok(header + res))
}
```

Sometimes this may take a while. So I figured cache it ...

```
  def annualAtomFill(peril: String, region: String) =
    cache("annualPerilRegion_" + peril + "_" + region) {
      Action.async {
        logger.trace("Retrieve and fill gaps peril ->" + peril + " :: region -> " + region)
        val events: Future[Seq[SingleEventYear]] = annualAtomFillInternal(peril, region)
        events.map(s => s.mkString("\n")).map(res => Ok(header + res))
      }
    }
```

Functionally, it appears to work very nicely. However, this appears to break the test...

```
 "event table" should {
"be a table with numIterations entries" in {
  val response = annualAtomFill("TC", "AUT")
  val aTest = response.apply(FakeRequest())
  val checkMe = contentAsString(aTest)
  checkMe.count(_ == '\n') mustBe this.numIterations
    }
}
```

Where aTest used to be a result. Now I get a compile problem...

```
    [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\Users\simon.parten\riskFactors\target\scala-2.11\test-classes...
[error] C:\Users\simon.parten\riskFactors\test\controllerTests\AepOepQuerySpec.scala:29: overloaded method value contentAsString with alternatives:
[error]   (of: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result])(implicit timeout: akka.util.Timeout, implicit mat: akka.stream.Materializer)String <and>
[error]   (of: play.twirl.api.Content)(implicit timeout: akka.util.Timeout)String
[error]  cannot be applied to (play.api.libs.streams.Accumulator[akka.util.ByteString,play.api.mvc.Result])
[error]       val checkMe = contentAsString(aTest)
[error]                     ^
[error] one error found
```

Because aTest is now a type of accumulator[ByteString, Result]. Ideas?

Comment: Oh, so sort of simple. We need to 'run' this accumulator apparently... for which we need some akka plumbing

Answer (score 0):

Oh, so sort of simple. We need to 'run' this accumulator apparently... for which we need some akka plumbing...

```
  implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
```

as properties of the spec

And then

```
val aTest = response.apply(FakeRequest()).run()
```